# group by ,multiindex, timeseris zscore calcuation slow (17 seconds) , need you clue to speed up

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

I am facing a performance issue of pandas rolling(expanding) 10 years history record zscore calculation. It is too slow 
for single recent day zscore, it need 17seconds 
for calculate to whole history, it need around 30 minutes.(I has already resample this history record to weekly level to downsize to total record.

If you are any advise to speed up my lastz function, pls feel free to share you idea.

**Here is the detail.**
**1. Data set.** a 10 years stock record which has been resampled to balance the size & accuracy. 
**Total size is (207376, 8)**
which covered about 500 index data for last 10 years. Here is the sample:

```
>               Close   PB1 PB2 PE1 PE2 TurnoverValue   TurnoverVol ROE  
>ticker tradeDate                               
>000001 2007-01-07  2678.526489 3.38135 2.87570 34.423700   61.361549 7.703712e+10  1.131558e+10    0.098227 
>2007-01-14 2755.759814 3.45878 3.09090 35.209019   66.407800   7.897185e+10    1.116473e+10    0.098236 
>2007-01-21 2796.761572 3.49394 3.31458 35.561800   70.449658   8.416415e+10    1.129387e+10    0.098250
```

2. I want to analyze the zscore changing in history and to forecast to future. 
   So, lastz function defined as below

The functions need speed up:

```
ts_start=pd.to_date("20180831")

@numba.jit
def lastz(x):
    if x.index.max()[1]<ts_start:
        return np.nan
    else:
        freedom = 1 # it is sample, so the sample std degree of freedome should not be 0 but 1

        nlimit_interpolate = int(len(x)/100) #1% fill allowed
        #print(nlimit_interpolate, len(x))
        x=x.interpolate(limit=nlimit_interpolate+1 ) # plus 1 in case of 0 or minus
        x=x.loc[x.notnull()]
        Arry=x.values
        zscore = stats.zmap(Arry[-1],Arry,ddof=freedom)
        return zscore


weekly = weekly.sort_index()
%prun -s cumtime result = weekly.groupby(level="ticker").agg(lastz)
```

Here is the prun results for single calling:
   13447048 function calls (13340521 primitive calls) in 17.183 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

```
>    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall
> filename:lineno(function)
>         1    0.000    0.000   17.183   17.183 {built-in method builtins.exec}
>         1    0.000    0.000   17.183   17.183 <string>:1(<module>)
>         1    0.000    0.000   17.176   17.176 groupby.py:4652(aggregate)
>         1    0.000    0.000   17.176   17.176 groupby.py:4086(aggregate)
>         1    0.000    0.000   17.176   17.176 base.py:562(_aggregate_multiple_funcs)
>      16/8    0.000    0.000   17.171    2.146 groupby.py:3471(aggregate)
>         8    0.000    0.000   17.171    2.146 groupby.py:3513(_aggregate_multiple_funcs)
>         8    0.000    0.000   17.147    2.143 groupby.py:1060(_python_agg_general)
>         8    0.000    0.000   17.145    2.143 groupby.py:2668(agg_series)
>         8    0.172    0.022   17.145    2.143 groupby.py:2693(_aggregate_series_pure_python)
>      4400    0.066    0.000   15.762    0.004 groupby.py:1062(<lambda>)
>      4400    0.162    0.000   14.255    0.003 <ipython-input-10-fdb784c8abd8>:15(lastz)
>      4400    0.035    0.000    8.982    0.002 base.py:807(max)
>      4400    0.070    0.000    7.955    0.002 multi.py:807(values)
>      4400    0.017    0.000    6.406    0.001 datetimes.py:976(astype)
>      4400    0.007    0.000    6.316    0.001 datetimelike.py:1130(astype)
>      4400    0.030    0.000    6.301    0.001 datetimelike.py:368(_box_values_as_index)
>      4400    0.009    0.000    5.613    0.001 datetimelike.py:362(_box_values)
>      4400    0.860    0.000    5.602    0.001 {pandas._libs.lib.map_infer}   1659008    4.278    0.000    4.741   
> 0.000 datetimes.py:606(<lambda>)
>      4328    0.096    0.000    1.774    0.000 generic.py:5980(interpolate)
>      4336    0.015    0.000    1.696    0.000 indexing.py:1463(__getitem__)
>      4328    0.028    0.000    1.675    0.000 indexing.py:1854(_getitem_axis)
```

I was wondering if the datatime compare call too frequency and  at better method to skip those calculated result. I calc the result weekly. So, last week data has already on hand no need to calculated again.  the index.max()[1] was used to check if the dataset is later than certain day. If newer, calculated, otherwise , just return nan.

if I used rolling or expanding mode, half hour or 2 hour will be need to get the result.

Appreciate any idea or clue to speed up the function.

Comment: looks no one answered yet. I found some clue which help to save to single time calculation  from 13s  to 5s.

Comment: looks no one answered yet. I found some clue which help to save to single time calculation  from 13s  to 5s.  As you may noticed that 6.4 seconds was used for datetime & index checking. it runned 4400 time.  the code is  index.max()[1]. I replace it with index[1][-1].      The datetime index related 6.4seconds saved. And total single runing time from 13S to 5s.  they secret is index[1][-1] use only 14us to get result, but index.max()[1] use  45ms. It is 3000time speed different.    However， I still think there should be better way to save the rolling & expanding related aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

[timeit result of different index method speed in pandas multiindex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhszI.jpg)

I change the index selection method to save 6 seconds for each single calculation.

However the total running time still too long to accepted. need you clue to optimize it.